# My puppy has either a black spot or gap within his iris- what is it?

Tags: dogs, health, eye-disease, puppy

My 13-week old puppy has a black spot within his iris- what is it?  From what I’ve gathered from an online search, it could be an “iris freckle” or coloboma.  Does anyone else have any ideas?  It would seem really young for such a young puppy to contract melanosis.  I plan to ask about it when I take him in this Friday for his second round of hepatitis and distemperment shots.
[image: puppy-eye-photo-with-black-spot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I visited the vet today and he said it was nothing to worry about.  Since the black speck within my puppy’s iris doesn’t have any mass, it’s just a benign irregular formation- and it’s not a coloboma or “iris freckle.”  Always consult your vet if you have a similar issue.